# std::lower_bound with skipping invalid elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, boost, time-complexity

I have a list of file names, with each representing a point in time. The list typically has thousands of elements. Given a time point, I'd like to convert these files names into time objects (I'm using `boost::ptime`), and then find the value of `std::lower_bound` of this time point with respect to the files names.

Example:

Filenames (with date + time, minutes increasing, with a minute for every file):

```
station01_20170612_030405.hdf5
station01_20170612_030505.hdf5
station01_20170612_030605.hdf5
station01_20170612_030705.hdf5
station01_20170612_030805.hdf5
station01_20170612_030905.hdf5
```

If I have a time-point `2017-06-12 03:06:00`, then it fits here:

```
station01_20170612_030405.hdf5
station01_20170612_030505.hdf5
                             <--- The lower bound I am looking for is here
station01_20170612_030605.hdf5
station01_20170612_030705.hdf5
station01_20170612_030805.hdf5
station01_20170612_030905.hdf5
```

So far, everything is simple. Now the problem is that the list of files  may be doped with some invalid file name, which will make the conversion to a time point fail.

Currently, I'm doing this the easy/inefficient way, and I'd like to optimize it, because this program will go on a server and the cost of operation matters. So,  the stupid way is: Create a new list with time points, and only push time points that are valid:

```
vector<ptime> filesListTimePoints;
filesListTimePoints.reserve(filesList.size());
ptime time;
for(long i = 0; i < filesList.size(); i++) {
    ErrorCode error = ConvertToTime(filesList[i], time);
    if(error.errorCode() == SUCCESS)
        filesListTimePoints.push_back(time);
}
//now use std::lower_bound() on filesListTimePoints
```

You see, the problem is that I'm using a linear solution with a problem that can be solved with `O(log(N))` complexity. I don't need to convert all files or even look at all of them!

**My question:  How can I embed this into `std::lower_bound`, such that it remains with optimal complexity?**

#### My idea of a possible solution:

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), there's a basic implementation of `std::lower_bound`. I'm thinking of modifying that to get a working solution. But I'm not sure what to do when a convesion fails, since this algorithm highly depends on monotonic behavior. Does this problem have a solution, even mathematically speaking?

Here's the version I'm thinking about initially:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
ForwardIt lower_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first, last);

    while (count > 0) {
        it = first; 
        step = count / 2; 
        std::advance(it, step);
        ErrorCode error = ConvertToTime(*it, time);
        if(error.errorCode() == SUCCESS)
        {
            if (*it < value) {
                first = ++it; 
                count -= step + 1; 
            }
            else
                count = step;
            }
        else {
            // skip/ignore this point?
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

My ultimate solution (which might sound stupid) is to make this method a mutator of the list, and erase elements that are invalid. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Can you implement you own `Compare` and pass that instead?

Comment: @Incomputable that's an impractical solution due to the monotonicity of the search method. A comparator will return true/false. What is the answer to be returned by this comparator when a filename is invalid?

Comment: So the invalid ones doesn't carry any ordering information?

Comment: @Incomputable Nope! Think about it... a random file thrown there in the list example I provided. How could it be associated with any time point? It's an invalid file actually and should be absolutely ignored.

Comment: You can also create another iterator then. Though engineering costs might be higher than rolling your own lower bound. Basically `operator++()` and postfix version will skip invalid ones.

Comment: @Incomputable Could you explain how that iterator helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146406/discussion-between-incomputable-and-the-quantum-physicist).

Comment: @gsamaras I'm going for the most general case. Consider some idiot using a text editor on one of these, and getting a cache file with the same base filename beside one of them. I know it's unlikely, but the program has to be reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply index by `optional<ptime>`. If you want to cache the converted values, consider making it a `multimap<optional<ptime>, File>`.

Better yet, make a datatype representing the file, and calculate the timepoint inside its constructor:

```
struct File {
     File(std::string fname) : _fname(std::move(fname)), _time(parse_time(_fname)) { }

      boost::optional<boost::posix_time::ptime> _time;
      std::string _fname;

      static boost::optional<boost::posix_time::ptime> parse_time(std::string const& fname) {
            // return ptime or boost::none
    }
};
```

Now, simply define `operator<` suitably or use e.g. boost::multi_index_container to index by `_time`

Further notes:

1. in case it wasn't clear, such a map/set will have it's own `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range` operations, and will obviously also work with `std::lower_bound` and friends.
2. there's always `filter_iterator` adaptor: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the big picture on how to use that class. First, did you mean: `multimap<File, optional<ptime>>`, since I have the list of files and a single time point to compare with? Also in that class, you're calling the parse function on construction. Doesn't that get all file names to be parsed if all files are in an array? Could you explain the recipe you have in mind to put this together?

Comment: I've given you some ingredients. Your recipe will depend on what kind of soup you want to brew.